# iOS NSNotificationCenter and push notifications

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, apple-push-notifications, nsnotificationcenter

By default, when a push (remote) notification is received, is a NSNotification posted to the default NSNotification center?

I know that `- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo` is called, but I'd like another class to know that a push notification was received.

Do I have to post a NSNotification by myself or is it automatically posted?

Comment: You have to do it yourself

Comment: Like @Aminoacids said, but I will add this bit (cause it just burned me). Be sure that the 'object' you are registering for on both the post and the addObserver... methods is the same. I was using 'self' at post time and 'nil' at observe time and it took me a while to figure out why my notification was never coming to the observer. Make them both the same.